# Wrapping on li tags every 6 results WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

Got stack with wraping result in li tags below are my codes

```
PHP Code

<ul>
    <li>
<?php

$counter = 0;

 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $counter++;
?>
    <div><?php the_title();</div>
<?php 
    if($counter%7 == 6){ echo '</li><li>'; } 

    endwhile;
?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My the first 6 Results are successfully wrap with li but got problem on second and third it wrap 7 results li instead of 6

**Results HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>Result 1</div>
        <div>Result 2</div>
        <div>Result 3</div>
        <div>Result 4</div>
        <div>Result 5</div>
        <div>Result 6</div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div>Result 7</div>
        <div>Result 8</div>
        <div>Result 9</div>
        <div>Result 10</div>
        <div>Result 11</div>
        <div>Result 12</div>
        <div>Result 13</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Result 14</div>
        <div>Result 15</div>
        <div>Result 16</div>
        <div>Result 17</div>
        <div>Result 18</div>
        <div>Result 19</div>
        <div>Result 20</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Result 21</div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I don't know if where I got wrong on my loop up there or I missed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($counter > 0 && $counter % 6 == 0) {
    echo '</li><li>';
}
```